# Can't call static method from class as variable name?

Tags: php, strategy-pattern, php-5.2

I'm using php 5.2.6. I have a strategy pattern, and the strategies have a static method. In the class that actually implements one of the strategies, it gets the name of the strategy class to instantiate. However, I wanted to call one of the static methods before instantiation, like this:

```
$strNameOfStrategyClass::staticMethod();
```

but it gives `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`.

```
$> cat test.php

<?

interface strategyInterface {
        public function execute();
        public function getLog();
        public static function getFormatString();
}


class strategyA implements strategyInterface {
        public function execute() {}
        public function getLog() {}
        public static function getFormatString() {}
}

class strategyB implements strategyInterface {
        public function execute() {}
        public function getLog() {}
        public static function getFormatString() {}
}

class implementation {
        public function __construct( strategyInterface $strategy ) {
                $strFormat = $strategy::getFormatString();
        }
}

$objImplementation = & new implementation("strategyB") ;

$> php test.php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /var/www/test.php on line 24

$> php -v

PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2010 03:25:57)
```

Would this work in 5.3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  That syntax was introduced in 5.3

To workaround for <= 5.2, you can use `call_user_func`:

```
call_user_func(array($className, $funcName), $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

or `call_user_func_array`:

```
call_user_func_array(array($className, $funcName), array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
```

But on another note, what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense...

Why have it as a static function?  Your constructor in `implementation` is expecting an object anyway (that's what `strategyInterface $strategy` is looking for).  Passing a string won't work, since strings don't implement interfaces.  So what I would do, is make the interface non-static, and then do something like:

```
$strategy = new StrategyB();
$implementation = new Implementation($strategy);
```

Then, in the constructor:

```
$strFormat = $strategy->getFormatString();
```

Or, if you really still want that method to be static you could do:

```
$strFormat = call_user_func(array(get_class($strategy), 'getFormatString'));
```

Oh, and `= & new` synax is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) (and doesn't do what you think it does anyway).

Comment: Having a brain fart today :P I don't want to pass an instantiated object to the implementing class, because I want to instantiate it on down the line, after the implementing class has created some data that the strategy needs. I'll think I'll need the `call_user_func_array()` anyway -- thanks for the great code!

Comment: Note that this only sort of works in 5.3. You can do "$foo::staticMethod()" but you cannot do "$this->foo = new Whatever(); $this->foo::staticMethod()".

Answer (score 0):

Type hinting is going to give you some problems:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   implementation::__construct() must
>   implement interface strategyInterface,
>   string given

Comment: Hm, brain fart this morning. Why didn't my php give me that error?

Comment: @user151841 - Because unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is detected at compile time, so you were getting that error... I fixed that with call_user_func() before even trying to run the code, and got the second error, which is a runtime error.